# Postgres. How to grant SELECT permissions automatically for new tables?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, sql-grant

I am setting up a Postgres DB (AWS/RDS) with multiple schemas and want to have granular access control.

Each schema correlates to an application. Typically an application will have a "write" user (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.), but some applications only needs to read (SELECT) from different schemas.

Inspired by this AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/
I face problems with "permission denied" for my readusers querying tables created by writeusers, even though I ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA someschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO some_read_role;
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create AWS RDS postgres (10.6) instance with masteruser postgres
2. (DB postgres) As user postgres:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE somedb LC_COLLATE 'da_DK.utf8' LC_CTYPE 'da_DK.utf8' ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE template0;
   ```
3. (DB somedb) As user postgres:

   ```
   REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE somedb FROM PUBLIC;
   CREATE SCHEMA clients;
   CREATE ROLE clients_read_role;
   GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE somedb TO clients_read_role;
   CREATE ROLE clients_write_role;
   GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE somedb TO clients_write_role;
   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA clients TO clients_read_role;
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA clients TO clients_read_role;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA clients GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO clients_read_role;
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA clients TO clients_read_role;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA clients GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO clients_read_role;
   GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA clients TO clients_write_role;
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA clients TO clients_write_role;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA clients GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO clients_write_role;
   GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA clients TO clients_write_role;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA clients GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO clients_write_role;
   ```
4. (DB somedb) As user postgres:

   ```
   CREATE USER clients_read WITH PASSWORD 'xxx';
   GRANT clients_read_role TO clients_read;
   CREATE USER clients_write WITH PASSWORD 'yyy';
   GRANT clients_write_role TO clients_write;
   ```
5. (DB somedb) As user clients_write (via LiquiBase):

   ```
   CREATE TABLE clients.sometable
   (
       id   serial primary key,
       name varchar(50) not null
   );
   ```
6. (DB somedb) as user clients_read:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM clients.sometable;
   ```

   [42501] ERROR: permission denied for relation sometable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html#SQL-ALTERDEFAULTPRIVILEGES-DESCRIPTION):

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be
>   created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

In other words, running `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` as user `postgres` only affects tables created by `postgres`.

To change the defaults for another user's tables, you need to specify which user:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE clients_write ...
```

Note that the defaults are not inherited, so the target role is `clients_write` (i.e. the user actually running the `CREATE TABLE` command, who will become the new table's owner). Defaults for `clients_write_role` will have no effect unless your users `SET ROLE clients_write_role;` before creating a table.