# GRANT ALL doesnt work for new tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, privileges, sql-grant

I have script to create user and grant all privileges for table in postgres

```
create user dev_api with encrypted password 'xxx';
grant all privileges on database dev to dev_api;
ALTER USER dev_api CREATEDB;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dev TO dev_api;
GRANT ALL ON schema public TO dev_api;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dev_api;
```

Privileges working for existing tables. Problem is that when I create new table I have not rights to read this new table.

Why?

How can I solve it in my script?

Comment: [Alter Default Priviliges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres. How to grant SELECT permissions automatically for new tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892104/postgres-how-to-grant-select-permissions-automatically-for-new-tables) or [Grant permissions to user for any new tables created in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309416/1048572)